# How to create bridging headers for Objc++ from existing .swift files

Tags: swift, objective-c++

I have a project that has a module written in swift, and I need to call the module/functions from ObjC++ code.

My understanding is I need bridging headers, but I can't seem to find instructions on how to create them, other than they "should automatically be created", which is clearly not the case here.

What is the process on creating bridging headers or is there a way to manually create them.